# Inject Saved State in ViewModelFactory with kodein

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection, kodein

I develop app with MVVM pattern. I want save UI when user rotate screen.

***MyViewModel.kt***

```
class MyViewModel(val repository: SomeRepository,
                       state : SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    private val savedStateHandle = state
    companion object {
        const val KEY = "KEY"
    }

    fun saveCityId(cityId: String) {
        savedStateHandle.set(CITY_KEY, cityId)
    }

    fun getCityId(): String? {
        return savedStateHandle.get(CITY_KEY)
    }

}
```

***ViewModelFactory.kt***

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class ViewModelFactory(
    private val repository: SomeRepository,
    private val state: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return MyViewModel(repository,state) as T
    }

}
```

I call it in MainActivity
***MainActivity.kt***

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(), KodeinAware {
    private val factory: ViewModelFactoryby instance()
    override val kodein by kodein()
    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    cityId = intent.getStringExtra("cityId") ?: viewModel.getCityId()
        if (cityId != null) {
            viewModel.saveCityId(cityId!!)
            viewModel.getCurrentWeather(cityId!!)
        }
}
```

Here i inject dependencies

***Application.kt***

```
class ForecastApplication: Application(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        import(androidXModule(this@ForecastApplication))

        bind<SomeApi>() with singleton {
            Retrofit.create()
        }

        bind<WeatherRepository>() with singleton {
            WeatherRepository(instance())
        }
        bind() from provider {
            WeatherViewModelFactory(
                instance(), instance()
            )
        }
}
}
```

And i have this error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simpleforecast/com.example.simpleapp.UI.Cities.Activity}:org.kodein.di.Kodein$NotFoundException: No binding found for bind<SavedStateHandle>() 
with ?<Activity>().? { ? }
```

How shoud i build ViewModelFactory and inject Saved State module for ViewModel?

Comment: In your bindings you do not have any `SavedStateHandle` so the `instance()` function cannot guess it for you. Where does your state comes from?

Answer (score 4):

`SavedStateHandle` is parameter which cannot be bound to the DI graph, because it's retrieved from `Fragment` (or `Activity`), therefore you need to do several steps in order to make it work:

1) DI viewmodel definition - since you have custom parameter, you need to use `from factory`:

```kotlin
bind() from factory { handle: SavedStateHandle ->
    WeatherViewModel(
        state = handle,
        repository = instance()
    )
}
```

2) ViewModel Factory - you need to inherit from `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory`

```kotlin
val vmFactory = object : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(this, arguments) {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, handle: SavedStateHandle): T {
        val vmFactory: ((SavedStateHandle) -> WeatherViewModel) = kodein.direct.factory()
        return vmFactory(handle) as T
    }
}
```

Inside of the `create` method you'd retrieve the factory from your DI graph (from step 1).

3) You retrieve ViewModel with the specified factory:

```
lateinit var vm : WeatherViewModel

fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    vm = ViewModelProvider(this, vmFactory)[WeatherViewModel::class.java]
}
```

or android KTX way:

```
val vm : WeatherViewModel by viewModels { vmFactory }
```